# Issues with video

Tags: unity, nvidia, freeze, gpu

Im having issues with the video on my HTPC. Sometimes, more or less within 30 minutes from boot, video freezes and I cant do anything (except move mouse around). Either Ctrl+Alt+F1 nor Ctrl+Alt+Supr work but Im able to SSH the machine. Is it a problem with the videocard? (GTX 560)
Thank you and sorry for my bad English

Comment: Do you see any process taking all the CPU when you type `top`?

Comment: No, I dont. Furthermore, this error happens when the computer is running idle. It has never happend while playing games.